# Symfony2 & Doctrine2 - Class 'Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener' not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I´m trying to make working doctrine2 extensions but it still wrotes me this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener' not found in /data/web/virtuals/48565/virtual/www/domains/kozusnikjan.com/Symfony/app/cache/prod/appProdDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1377

And I don´t know, how to solve the problem. Please, help. Here are some files:

- http://pastebin.com/k9rqvGQn  -- config.yml
- http://pastebin.com/TvxbvEyS  -- doctrine-extensions.yml
- http://pastebin.com/prUFmrTb  -- AppKernel.php
- http://pastebin.com/0zAaHwW9  -- DoctrineExtensionListener.php

Thank you very much

Edit:
New files:

- http://pastebin.com/qEAZtFba  -- composer.json
- http://pastebin.com/aBnvrZj9  -- config.yml
- http://pastebin.com/E1aSSddm  -- appKernel.php

I edited this files. I didn´t create any file.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're using stof extension bundle???

Answer (score 1):

You're using Gedmo directly. Try through StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle...
If you are using composer add to your composer.json at require section

```
"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.*@dev"
```

and run composer update. You must load bundle on AppKernel.

then put on your config.yml

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: %locale%
    orm:
        default:
            tree: true
```

May be you wanna find your problem, but I use Gedmo this way and works fine.

Comment: Indeed, stof make it easier

Comment: So I will put to my config.yml this lines instead orm ... but, aren´t this lines only for Tree? Is there any way to use it for all extensions - tree, translateable...?

Comment: install doctrine stof and read documentation...  you could use all extensions. StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle integrates gedmo and bridge internals to symfony2 properly.

Comment: I tried to install StofDoctrineExtensionBundle like this: https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst but it wrotes this:
**Class 'ComposerAutoloaderInitc92a9075fd464390793ca99b6d33705a' not found in /data/web/virtuals/48565/virtual/www/domains/kozusnikjan.com/Symfony/vendor/autoload.php on line 7**  I post new files in first question

Comment: Now it wrotes this: ** Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException' with message 'Unrecognized options "gedmo_translatable, gedmo_translator, gedmo_loggable, gedmo_tree" under "doctrine.orm.entity_managers.mappings"' ** probably problem in formating config.yml. But where?

Comment: Well i intall stof using composer, i never deal with first error,but may be you forgot include stof bundle on AppKernel.php. Second the config using stof it's little different, see stof documentation, a look to Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration would help too.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old Problem, but I had this one too today. Solved it by declaring the tree listener as a service:
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md#doctrine-extension-listener-services

It's the same for every Gedmo extension such as translatable, sluggable, timestampable...